# SharePoint Online sitegroups REST query in graph API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, graph-api

I have a question regarding quering site groups via REST Graph API instead of SharePoint REST API. Currently I need to query SharePoint REST API to find implicit groups (*Visitors, *Members, *Owners) for each site in order to find users that are members of those groups (those groups are not present in groups Graph API). To achieve this I am using two queries. First:

```
https://{site_url}/sites/{ site name}/_api/Web/SiteGroups
```

to obtain list of implicit groups with type ids, and then:

```
https://{site_url}/sites/{ site name}/_api/Web/SiteGroups/GetById({id})/Users
```

to obtain list of users in one specific group obtained from first query.

So the question is: **Are any equivalents to those two queries above in REST Graph API or I need still to obtain those information from SharePoint REST API?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for the Sites endpoint (both v1.0 and beta), it does not appear that you can get SharePoint Permission Groups or their members from the Graph.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/site?view=graph-rest-1.0

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/site?view=graph-rest-beta

Answer (score 0):

It seems that now Owners and Members can be accessed via the Graph API. See [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1253588/how-to-access-sharepoint-site-security-group-using?page=1).

Site groups now appear under `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/`, and you can access owners and members with

- [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/owners](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%7BgroupId%7D/owners)
- [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/members](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%7BgroupId%7D/members)

respectively

However, I still do not see a way to access visitors

Alternatively, per [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1181317/how-to-get-sharepoint-site-default-group-like-owee), it seems that you can query a site's User Information List, and then see the `ContentType: Person` results to find who it has been shared with.

Answer (score -1):

As per my understanding currently Microsoft Graph does not support working with SharePoint groups and we can only work with **Sites**, **Lists** and **ListItems** using Microsoft Graph (correct me if I am wrong).

**Source**: [Working with SharePoint sites in Microsoft Graph](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint).

**Workaround**:

1. Go with traditional SharePoint REST APIs as you are already using.
2. Use **PnPJS** library to get SharePoint Site groups and Group members easily.

**References**: [@pnp/sp/site-groups](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/site-groups/).