# Getting a SharepPoint group's members using graph API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, groups, microsoft-graph, graph-api

Unfortunately I can't access the old SharePoint API.

I managed to get the names of the SharePoint groups using GraphAPI, and some information about them, but I couldn't find a way to retrieve their members.

Thank you,

Comment: I think it is not possible to get sharepoint group members. check my answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/275511/sharepoint-online-sitegroups-rest-query-in-graph-api/275514#275514). you can only get the office 365 group members. check [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members).

Comment: Thank you. Yes I know I can get these groups, but unfortunately I need sharepoint groups, which are not returned by this endpoint...

Comment: I can understand but Microsoft graph does not support getting SharePoint groups members.

Comment: Actually, as I said, I can get the sharepoint groups using the graph api, getting the members is a different story though

Comment: Can you please post the endpoint you are using to get the SharePoint groups?

Comment: First I get the user lists
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/root/lists?$select=id,system,name
the system in select is important because otherwise this list will not be returned. I can't seem to filter it, but we need the list called "users"
then I just list its items, and look for items with the type SharePointGroup:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/root/lists/{list_id}/items

It's a bit of a mess, and definitely not ideal, but it does the job